# How to initialize variables in oracle before next iteration of the loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure in which i have used lots of variables, The variables gets the values by select queries inside a loop. Now whenever the next iteration of the loop start i want all the variables should be reinitialized, i.e all values from previous iteration should be gone. I have tried it through setting manually all of them to null or zero, but it is lethargic..Is there a better way to do so?

```
BEGIN

  FOR I IN (SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS) LOOP

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO V_CNT1 FROM TABLE1 T WHERE T.ID = I.ID;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO V_CNT2 FROM TABLE2 T WHERE T.ID = I.ID;

    V_CNT := V_CNT1 + V_CNT2;

    V_CNT  := 0;
    V_CNT1 := 0;
    V_CNT2 := 0;

  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve here? You fetch the values by select statement and then add the values and then assign it Zero. So the outcome is anyways Zero. Whats the requirement ? In a loop, you have to go via this way only, else you can do bulk opration and ignore loop.

Comment: Its just a sample code XING..

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't have to do anything.

`select count(*)` will return 0 even if it doesn't find anything, so both `v_cnt1` and `v_cnt2` will be *reinitialized* automatically, which propagates to `v_cnt` as it'll get sum of last values of `v_cnt1 + v_cnt2`.

I understand that this is just a sample code. If - in reality - it isn't that simple, then initialize variables **when necessary**. Usually, it is right after the `LOOP` keyword, but doesn't have to be. It depends on what & when you are doing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the trouble, put the variables that make sense together into records. You can define your working record and an initialized record that never changes, and you can copy the initialized record to the working record in one go.

```
declare
  type t_rec is record(
    v1 number,
    v2 varchar2(22),
    v3 integer,
    v4 date
  );
  c constant t_rec := new t_rec(0, null, 0, null);
  l t_rec;
begin
  for i in 1..3 loop
    l := c;
    dbms_output.put_line(l.v1);
    select 1, 'a', 2, sysdate into l from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(l.v1);
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

0
1
0
1
0
1
```